# Why does my ffmpeg audio sound slower and deeper - sample rate mismatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, ffmpeg, discord.js

ok so this is a discord bot to record voice chat
https://hatebin.com/hgjlazacri
Now the bot works perfectly fine but the issue is that the audio sounds a bit deeper and slower than normal.. Why does it happen? how can I make the audio sound 1:1..

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ffmpegInstaller = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegInstaller.path);
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const mergeStream = require('merge-stream');
const config = require('./config.json');
const { getAudioDurationInSeconds } = require('get-audio-duration');
const cp = require('child_process');
const path1 = require('path');
const Enmap = require('enmap');
const UserRecords = require("./models/userrecords.js")
const ServerRecords = require("./models/serverrecords.js")
let prefix = `$`
class Readable extends require('stream').Readable { _read() {} }
let recording = false;
let currently_recording = {};
let mp3Paths = [];
const silence_buffer = new Uint8Array(3840);
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const publicIP = require('public-ip')
const { program } = require('commander');
const { path } = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg');
const version = '0.0.1'
program.version(version);
let debug = false
let runProd = false
let fqdn = "";
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mongoose.connect('SECRRET',{
  useNewUrlParser: true
}, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    console.log("Database connection initiated");
  }
});
require("dotenv").config()
function bufferToStream(buffer) {
    let stream = new Readable();
    stream.push(buffer);
    return stream;
}





client.commands = new Enmap();

client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);

    let host = "localhost"

    

    let ip = await publicIP.v4();

    let protocol = "http";
    if (!runProd) {
        host = "localhost"
    } else {
        host = `35.226.244.186`;
    }
    fqdn = `${protocol}://${host}:${port}`
    app.listen(port, `0.0.0.0`, () => {
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port} for ${host} at fqdn ${fqdn}`)
    })
});
let randomArr = []
let finalArrWithIds = []
let variable = 0
client.on('message', async message => {
    console.log(`fuck`);
    if(message.content === `$record`){
        mp3Paths = []
        finalArrWithIds = []
        let membersToScrape = Array.from(message.member.voice.channel.members.values());
        membersToScrape.forEach((member) => {
            if(member.id === `749250882830598235`) {
                console.log(`botid`);
            }
            else {
                finalArrWithIds.push(member.id)
            }
            
        })
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        randomArr = []
        randomArr.push(randomNumber)
    }
   
    
    const generateSilentData = async (silentStream, memberID) => {
        console.log(`recordingnow`)
        while(recording) {
            if (!currently_recording[memberID]) {
                silentStream.push(silence_buffer);
            }
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 20));
        }
        return "done";
    }
    console.log(generateSilentData, `status`)
    function generateOutputFile(channelID, memberID) {
        const dir = `./recordings/${channelID}/${memberID}`;
        fs.ensureDirSync(dir);
        const fileName = `${dir}/${randomArr[0]}.aac`;
        console.log(`${fileName} ---------------------------`);
        return fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
    }
    
    if (!fs.existsSync("public")) {
        fs.mkdirSync("public");
    }
    app.use("/public", express.static("./public"));
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content === config.prefix + config.record_command) {
    if (recording) {
        message.reply("bot is already recording");
        return
    }
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
        recording = true;
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        const dispatcher = connection.play('./audio.mp3');

        connection.on('speaking', (user, speaking) => {
            if (speaking.has('SPEAKING')) {
                currently_recording[user.id] = true;
            } else {
                currently_recording[user.id] = false;
            }
        })


        let members = Array.from(message.member.voice.channel.members.values());
        members.forEach((member) => {

            if (member.id != client.user.id) {
                let memberStream = connection.receiver.createStream(member, {mode : 'pcm', end : 'manual'})

                let outputFile = generateOutputFile(message.member.voice.channel.id, member.id);
                console.log(outputFile, `outputfile here`);
                mp3Paths.push(outputFile.path);
                    

                silence_stream = bufferToStream(new Uint8Array(0));
                generateSilentData(silence_stream, member.id).then(data => console.log(data));
                let combinedStream = mergeStream(silence_stream, memberStream);

                ffmpeg(combinedStream)
                    .inputFormat('s32le')
                    .audioFrequency(44100)
                    .audioChannels(2)
                    .on('error', (error) => {console.log(error)})
                    .audioCodec('aac')
                    .format('adts') 
                    .pipe(outputFile)
                    
            }
        })
    } else {
      message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
    }
  }

  if (message.content === config.prefix + config.stop_command) {

    let date = new Date();
    let dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    let mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); 
    let yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    date = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;





    let currentVoiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (currentVoiceChannel) {
        recording = false;
        await currentVoiceChannel.leave();

        let mergedOutputFolder = './recordings/' + message.member.voice.channel.id + `/${randomArr[0]}/`;
        fs.ensureDirSync(mergedOutputFolder);
        let file_name = `${randomArr[0]}` + '.aac';
        let mergedOutputFile = mergedOutputFolder + file_name;
    
        
    let download_path = message.member.voice.channel.id + `/${randomArr[0]}/` + file_name;

        let mixedOutput = new ffmpeg();
        console.log(mp3Paths, `mp3pathshere`);
        mp3Paths.forEach((mp3Path) => {
             mixedOutput.addInput(mp3Path);
            
        })
        console.log(mp3Paths);
        //mixedOutput.complexFilter('amix=inputs=2:duration=longest');
        mixedOutput.complexFilter('amix=inputs=' + mp3Paths.length + ':duration=longest');
        
        let processEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle(`Audio Processing.`)
        processEmbed.addField(`Audio processing starting now..`, `Processing Audio`)
        processEmbed.setThumbnail(`https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/730811581046325348/748610998985818202/speaker.png`)
        processEmbed.setColor(` #00FFFF`)
        const processEmbedMsg = await message.channel.send(processEmbed)
        async function saveMp3(mixedData, outputMixed) {
            console.log(`${mixedData} MIXED `)
            
            
            
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                mixedData.on('error', reject).on('progress',
                async (progress) => {
                    
                    let processEmbedEdit = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle(`Audio Processing.`)
                    processEmbedEdit.addField(`Processing: ${progress.targetSize} KB converted`, `Processing Audio`)
                    processEmbedEdit.setThumbnail(`https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/730811581046325348/748610998985818202/speaker.png`)
                    processEmbedEdit.setColor(` #00FFFF`)
                    processEmbedMsg.edit(processEmbedEdit)
                    console.log('Processing: ' + progress.targetSize + ' KB converted');
                }).on('end', () => {
                    console.log('Processing finished !');
                    resolve()
                }).saveToFile(outputMixed);
                console.log(`${outputMixed} IT IS HERE`);
            })
        }
        // mixedOutput.saveToFile(mergedOutputFile);
        await saveMp3(mixedOutput, mergedOutputFile);
        console.log(`${mixedOutput} IN HEREEEEEEE`);
        // We saved the recording, now copy the recording
        if (!fs.existsSync(`./public`)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(`./public`);
        }
        let sourceFile = `${__dirname}/recordings/${download_path}`
        console.log(`DOWNLOAD PATH HERE ${download_path}`)
        const guildName = message.guild.id;
        const serveExist = `/public/${guildName}`
        if (!fs.existsSync(`.${serveExist}`)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(`.${serveExist}`)
        }
        let destionationFile = `${__dirname}${serveExist}/${file_name}`

        let errorThrown = false
        try {
            fs.copySync(sourceFile, destionationFile);
        } catch (err) {
            errorThrown = true
            await message.channel.send(`Error: ${err.message}`)
        }
        const usersWithTag = finalArrWithIds.map(user => `\n <@${user}>`);
        let timeSpent = await getAudioDurationInSeconds(`public/${guildName}/${file_name}`)
        let timesSpentRound = Math.floor(timeSpent)
        let finalTimeSpent = timesSpentRound / 60
        let finalTimeForReal = Math.floor(finalTimeSpent)
        if(!errorThrown){
            //--------------------- server recording save START
            class GeneralRecords {
                constructor(generalLink, date, voice, time) {
                  this.generalLink = generalLink;
                  this.date = date;
                  this.note = `no note`;
                  this.voice = voice;
                  this.time = time
                }
              }
              let newGeneralRecordClassObject = new GeneralRecords(`${fqdn}/public/${guildName}/${file_name}`, date, usersWithTag, finalTimeForReal)
              let checkingServerRecord = await ServerRecords.exists({userid: `server`})
              if(checkingServerRecord === true){
                  existingServerRecord = await ServerRecords.findOne({userid: `server`})
                  existingServerRecord.content.push(newGeneralRecordClassObject)
                  await existingServerRecord.save()
              }
              if(checkingServerRecord === false){
                let serverRecord = new ServerRecords()
                serverRecord.userid = `server`
                serverRecord.content.push(newGeneralRecordClassObject)
                await serverRecord.save()
              }
              //--------------------- server recording save STOP
        }
        
        //--------------------- personal recording section START
        for( member of finalArrWithIds) {

        let personal_download_path = message.member.voice.channel.id + `/${member}/` + file_name;
        let sourceFilePersonal = `${__dirname}/recordings/${personal_download_path}`
        let destionationFilePersonal = `${__dirname}${serveExist}/${member}/${file_name}`
        await fs.copySync(sourceFilePersonal, destionationFilePersonal);
        const user = client.users.cache.get(member);
        console.log(user, `user here`);
        try {
            ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegInstaller.path);
          
            ffmpeg(`public/${guildName}/${member}/${file_name}`)
             .audioFilters('silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_duration=1:stop_threshold=-90dB')
             .output(`public/${guildName}/${member}/personal-${file_name}`)
             .on(`end`, function () {
               console.log(`DONE`);
             })
             .on(`error`, function (error) {
               console.log(`An error occured` + error.message)
             })
             .run();
             
          }
          catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
          }
        

        // ----------------- SAVING PERSONAL RECORDING TO DATABASE START
        class PersonalRecords {
            constructor(generalLink, personalLink, date, time) {
              this.generalLink = generalLink;
              this.personalLink = personalLink;
              this.date = date;
              this.note = `no note`;
              this.time = time;
            }
          }
          let timeSpentPersonal = await getAudioDurationInSeconds(`public/${guildName}/${file_name}`)
          let timesSpentRoundPersonal = Math.floor(timeSpentPersonal)
          let finalTimeSpentPersonal = timesSpentRoundPersonal / 60
          let finalTimeForRealPersonal = Math.floor(finalTimeSpentPersonal)
          let newPersonalRecordClassObject = new PersonalRecords(`${fqdn}/public/${guildName}/${file_name}`, `${fqdn}/public/${guildName}/${member}/personal-${file_name}`, date, finalTimeForRealPersonal)

           let checkingUserRecord = await UserRecords.exists({userid: member})
              if(checkingUserRecord === true){
                  existingUserRecord = await UserRecords.findOne({userid: member})
                  existingUserRecord.content.push(newPersonalRecordClassObject)
                  await existingUserRecord.save()
              }
              if(checkingUserRecord === false){
                let newRecord = new UserRecords()
                newRecord.userid = member
                newRecord.content.push(newPersonalRecordClassObject)
                await newRecord.save()
              }


       
        // ----------------- SAVING PERSONAL RECORDING TO DATABASE END
       

        const endPersonalEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle(`Your performance was amazing ! Review it here :D`)
        endPersonalEmbed.setColor('#9400D3')
        endPersonalEmbed.setThumbnail(`https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/730811581046325348/745381641324724294/vinyl.png`)
        endPersonalEmbed.addField(` Date`, `${date}`)
        endPersonalEmbed.addField(`⏰ Time spent by you`, `${finalTimeForRealPersonal} minute(s)`)
        endPersonalEmbed.addField(` Download`, `${fqdn}/public/${guildName}/${member}/personal-${file_name}`)
        endPersonalEmbed.setFooter(`Use \`$myrecordings\` to get a list of all your recordings !`)

        user.send(endPersonalEmbed)
    }
         // ----------------- personal recording section OVER

        
         const endEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle(`I will be honest, that recording session was sick !`)
         endEmbed.setColor('#9400D3')
         endEmbed.addField(`️ Voices`, usersWithTag)
         endEmbed.addField(`⏰ Time spent`, `${finalTimeForReal} minute(s)`)
         endEmbed.addField(` Download`, `${fqdn}/public/${guildName}/${file_name}`)
         endEmbed.setThumbnail(`https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/730811581046325348/745370416352067704/microphone.png`)
         endEmbed.setFooter(`Check your DMs for a recording of your personal voice during this session.`)
        message.channel.send(endEmbed)
        
        
    } else {
      message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
    }









    
  } 
  if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return;


  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const cmd = client.commands.get(command);

  if (!cmd) return;

  cmd.run(client, message, args);
});

fs.readdir('./commands/', async (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error;
    files.forEach(file => {
        if (!file.endsWith('.js')) return;
        let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        let cmdName = file.split('.')[0];
        console.log(`Loaded command '${cmdName}'`);

        // Register extra Listeners
        

        client.commands.set(cmdName, props);
    });
});



async function main() {
    program.option('-debug')
    program.option('-prod')

    program.parse(process.argv)

    console.log(program.opts())
    if (program.Debug != undefined) {
      debug = !debug
    }
    if (program.Prod != undefined) {
      runProd = !runProd
    }
    if (runProd) {
        client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN_PROD).catch(e => {
            console.log("ERROR")
            console.log(e)
        })
    } else {
        client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN_TEST).catch(e => {
            console.log("ERROR")
            console.log(e)
        })
    }
}
main()
```

Now the bot works perfectly fine but the issue is that the audio sounds a bit deeper and slower than normal.. Why does it happen? how can I make the audio sound 1:1..
How do i fix the sample rate mismatch
Note; I have already tried to set Audio freq as 48000 but it has made no difference.

Comment: What if you drop the audio sample rate setting altogether?

Comment: drop the sample rate setting ?
I don't quite understand 

Comment: Remove/delete this line entirely:                      `.audioFrequency(44100)`

Comment: @Brad
yeah, that defo made it better, although I do think that the voice is still a tipsy bit deeper than normal..